# Temporarily force windows 8 (surface pro) throttled speed towards the max allowed?

Tags: python, windows-8.1

I'm running some python scripts on a surface pro 3 i7, and I noticed that when the system processor speed is reduced (tends to idle around 0.76 GHz) my script takes 10 seconds or more. However if the system has just been active, and the speed is nearer the 2.3 GHz max, the script takes closer to 6 seconds.

Is there any neat way (preferably using python) to bring the speed up temporarily? I'm talking 30 seconds at most, and my script is very un-intensive.. it just runs a lot quicker.

Comment: You would need to tell the Operating System to do stuff with the CPU governor. It's probably much easier to just put your machine in 'high performance' mode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. High performance mode isn't available by default on surface pro's, but [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/290hmy/hyperv_power_plans_on_surface_pro_3/) lead me to trying out hyper-v. Now the processor sits at max, even on power-saver mode, and things seem a little snappier, but timings still fluctuate up to 10 seconds. I think the surface pro just has some performance issues I'll have to live with

Comment: use an external USB fan to reduce the throttling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uC8rCeDMqFw

Comment: My problem isn't actually that the processor is getting throttled due to thermal issues.. my script actually has very low processor usage, so the processor is being throttled down because windows thinks the system is idling. As a result the script goes slower. It actually runs faster while other things are going on. It feels weird to do, but I may build in a dummy intensive process just before my script to bring the speed up